FBInstant games error when loading images from url due to Content Security Policy
Hi im currently making a game for facebook and i ran into a problem regarding content security policy:
error message
I tried changing the content security policy a bunch of times, in the end i decided to add all the links in the error message and it still doesnt work.
this is my current Content Security Policy thingy that doesnt work:
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="img-src * 'self' https: blob: data: *.pub-3626123a908346a7a8be8d9295f44e26.r2.dev ;">

The CSP values from the error message don't appear to come from your app in the first place, Facebook sets those. Instant Games are hosted on Facebook, I don't think you are supposed to embed any external resources to begin with ...?

It's a bug in Facebook. They claim that it's solved while everyone keep seeing this error.
https://developers.facebook.com/support/bugs/1467479687167103/
